# CursorLoader to query data inside IntentService implementation

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-intentservice

I have an intent-service which runs practically, infinitely, till a static kill Boolean is set to true or some specific condition calls stopSelf(). (is this a good idea ?)
My service depends on querying a content-provider.
Now I did not want to "poll" the provider for changes, so I tried

```
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(uri, false, contentObserver);
```

I define my ContentObserver like this :

```
private final ContentObserver contentObserver = new ContentObserver(new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())) {
        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            super.onChange(selfChange);
            if(kill) {
                Log.i("Downloader", "Unregister observer");
                getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(contentObserver);
                return;
            }
            //Must submit to a thread else, UI gets blocked
            executor.execute(updater);
        }
    };

private final Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

"updater" is simple Runnable which reQueries the object I'm observing.

So far, this model seems to be working. When the URI im observing gets deleted I exit my service using stopSelf(). Basically this service is started to monitor a particular URI for changes. The inbuilt queuing of intent service really works out for me.
I have 2 questions :

1. Is there a better way to supply a handler than using the main Looper ?
   If I use the handler of my service's thread all the "messages" are delivered to onChange after my service dies (if i do not unregister the observer)
2. Is this model sensible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is this a good idea ?

IMHO, no. Use a regular `Service` and manage your own background thread. Then use `stopService()`, or a message delivered to the service via `startService()`, instead of "a static kill Boolean".

> Is there a better way to supply a handler than using the main Looper ?

Use a regular `Service` and fork your own [`HandlerThread`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html), then use its `Looper`. Then you can get rid of the separate `Executor`, and you still do not have to worry about tying up the main application thread, as you do with the main thread's `Looper`.

Comment: I lol'ed when I saw you double quoted my kill boolean :D. Your model looks a lot neater. I'll use it. Thanks. Will accept soon enough.